# Loading data in activity before creating fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new at android development and i want to load data from Firebase before creating fragment so that activity can decide which fragment to load based on data retrieved. The fragment contents depend on data retrieved.

```
public class QuestionsPagerActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {


private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private Question question;
private ArrayList<Question> mQuestionsList;


public static Intent NewIntent(Context packageContext) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, QuestionsPagerActivity.class);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("questionspageracitivity", "okay");
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("questions");

    mQuestionsList = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                question = snapshot.getValue(Question.class);
                mQuestionsList.add(question);


                Log.d("quizacitivty", "" + mQuestionsList.get(mQuestionsList.size() - 1).getQuesiton());

            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}


@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {


    if ((mQuestionsList.size()) > 0) {
        if (mQuestionsList.get(0).getOptionOne() == null) {
            return TextQuizFragment.newInstance(mQuestionsList.get(0).getQuesiton());
        } else {

            return MCQQuizFragment.newInstance(mQuestionsList.get(0).getQuesiton(), mQuestionsList.get(0).getOptionOne(), mQuestionsList.get(0).getOptionTwo(), mQuestionsList.get(0).getOptionThree(), mQuestionsList.get(0).getOptionFour());
        }

    } else {
        return null;
    }



}

public void replaceFragment() {


    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if ((mQuestionsList.size()) > 0) {

        if (mQuestionsList.get(0).getOptionOne() == null) {

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, TextQuizFragment.newInstance(mQuestionsList.get(0).getQuesiton()));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MCQQuizFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        mQuestionsList.remove(mQuestionsList.get(0));
    }
}}
```

Comment: You can use dynamic fragment for this.

Comment: I have used dynamic fragment @krish

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a fragment to the activity during the activity runtime.

Please check below code

**res/layout/news_articles.xml:**

*An important rule when dealing with fragments—especially when adding fragments at runtime—is that your activity layout must include a container* View in which you can insert the fragment.

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Check your condition and do the navigation during in runtime

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            //Check your condition based on firebase response
            if (myFirebaseCondition) {
                // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
                HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
                // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
            } else {
                // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
                DescriptionFragment descriptionFragment = new DescriptionFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container, descriptionFragment).commit();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Follow [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) to know more about fragment

Comment: Where should i retrieve firebase records in code so i can perform if else statement. @Rissmon Suresh

Comment: Try inside OnDatachanged() method?

Comment: OnDatachanged() not available in activity. And I want to call firebase record before creating fragments not after fragment created